# Unable to locate package libicu60

Tags: package-management, r, rstudio

I'm trying to install the R programming language on Ubuntu. I've followed these instructions but there appears to be missing dependency that I cannot install.

https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/

I've Googled... but nothing stands out... what am I missing?

```
kye@DEVRSTUDIO:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
kye@DEVRSTUDIO:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Get:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:3 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Get:4 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 Packages [261 kB]
Get:5 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/universe amd64 Packages [203 kB]
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease      
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Fetched 650 kB in 1s (501 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
15 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
kye@DEVRSTUDIO:~$ sudo apt install libicu60
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libicu60
kye@DEVRSTUDIO:~$
```

Comment: The instructions in your link don't appear to include Ubuntu 19.10 - what steps did you perform, exactly?

Comment: The link is correct. Instructions for different distributions are on tabs.

Comment: As of today, `libicu60` package is still only avaliable in Ubuntu 18.04, and for anyone using a more recent version of Ubuntu 21.**, you may want to use `libicu67` instead.

Comment: @7kemZmani When binaries ask for `libicu60`, they generally won't work with `libicu67`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `libicu60` is [ONLY available in Ubuntu 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libicu60). It's not available in any releases before nor after.

You can try getting the 18.04 package from http://packages.ubuntu.com and installing it locally, but there is no guarantee that it will work.

- To install a package that you downloaded, use `sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb`. (Obviously, you must provide the path and the package name)

Comment: Your right. I created a new machine, reinstalled everything, success!. Thank you.